# How to find the shortest number in a file

Tags: awk

I'm trying to find the shortest number in the file but I do not know how to do it
This is my input file:

```
asd
qwmcqm
342
xsa
53425423432
54334
aseqwe
// so i want to print "342"
```

It has to be AWK script so i can't use "sort" (in shell), i've tried this:

```
while(( getline line < "FileInput" ) > 0 ){
if ( line ~ /[0-9]/ )
if (length(line) < L)
    L = length(line)
}
```

but it doesn't work! It works only for largest number if i change "<" to ">" inside script.

Comment: Why do you need to use `sort` in the shell? Is that part of the assignment? `awk` has built-in sorting functions (`asort` and `asorti`).

Comment: You should define your terms. Is `1.00` a number? Which is “shorter”, `1.00` or `42`? Is `0xC` a number? Etc.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Also, do you just want to print `342`? If so, a simple `grep` to `sort` to `head` will do.

Comment: FYI using `getline` in this way is non-idiomatic - and unnecessary since awk reads and processes line-by-line (or, more formally, record-by-record) anyhow

Answer (score 3):

The reason that your example works for finding the largest number and not the smallest number is because variables in `awk` which have not been explicitly set, default to 0. None of your matching lines will be less than 0.

Since you are wanting to compare with previously found numbers, you can ensure that the length of the first number found is set to L by including a check if L is 0 in your conditional (which will only be the case if it is the first number seen in the file).

```
if (length(line) < L || L == 0) {
   L = length(line)
}
```

Comment: Or to get the actual number as stated, using the default loop: `awk '/^[0-9]+$/ && (length<length(X) || !length(X)) {X=$0} END{print X}'` (Can add `BEGIN{X=""}` if desired but not needed; vars actually default to empty string which _converts_ to zero.)